# Comparable polynomials with non-negative coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let ${p, q \in \mathbb{R}[x]}$ be polynomials with non-negative coefficients.
Assume that ${p(r) \leq q(r)}$ for every ${r \geq 0}$.

Is it the case that ${q - p}$ has non-negative coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't true : take $q(x)=x^2+1$ and $p(x)=x.$

Indeed $r(x):=q(x)-p(x)=x^2-x+1$ is positive for all $x$ (positive or negative).

Comment: Consider the semi-ring of polynomials with non-negative coefficients. One may partially order it by comparing polynomials as functions. On the other hand, one could say that ${p \leq q}$ iff there is a $d$ such that ${p + d = q}$. Your example shows that these two partial orders are different. I have the feeling that there is something more to be said here but I am not sure. Could you add some more information @Jean Marie?

Comment: Among the possible orders among polynomials with positive coefficients over $\mathbb{R}^+$, it looks to me that the order you mention is the lexicographical ordering. Isn't it ?

Comment: I think so; yes.

Comment: Besides, thanks for correcting.